# How to create an alert E-mail notification for Gauge dashboard

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts

For your reference i have attached the image of my dashboard below. My requirement is i have to send an alert E-mail whenever the value reached the threshold limit but here the challenge is i am not able to create an alert E-mail notification for Gauge dashboard because i am not able to locate the alert icon.

[image]

Could some one help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't** - or actually **you can**. Meaning that for now it is only possible to set up alarms using a graph - therefore it is not possible to set up Gauge-alerts, if that is what you are looking for.

From the documentation:

> Currently only the graph panel supports alert rules.

**Workaround**

(*which is actually quite simple to setup - especially if you only have 6 gauges*)
:
So my suggestion would be to create a graph with the queries + alert conditions and setup your notification channels.
In your alert conditions you can specify each query (A, B, C, etc). One for each gauge..

[image: Alert conditions]

For reference check out the documentation: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/rules/

If that isn't what you are looking for then please specify the question, and I will gladly help.